# Inverse string case

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to write a function that takes the string and changes all the lowercase letters to uppercase and vice versa. "lower UPPER" would translate to "LOWER upper"

Heres what I have:

```
var convertString = function (str){
var s = '';
var i = 0;
while (i < str.length) {
    var n = str.charAt(i);
        if (n == n.toUpperCase()) {
            n = n.toLowerCase;
        }
        else {
            n = n.toUpperCase;
        }

 i +=1; 
 s += n;

}
return s;
};
convertString("lower UPPER");
```

I'm using [this website](http://labs.codecademy.com/#:workspace) to work and am getting a pretty weird message outputted.

[Here is a pic of what happens after I run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpgzT.jpg)

Comment: `'lower UPPER'.replace(/./g, c => c === c.toUpperCase() ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have just about everything correct, except for inside of your `if` statement. You're setting `n` equal to its `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` *method*, not its return value. You need to call those methods and set `n` equal to their return values:

```
var convertString = function (str) {
    var s = '';
    var i = 0;
    while (i < str.length) {
        var n = str.charAt(i);
        if (n == n.toUpperCase()) {
            // *Call* toLowerCase
            n = n.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            // *Call* toUpperCase
            n = n.toUpperCase();
        }

        i += 1;
        s += n; 
    }
    return s;
};

convertString("lower UPPER");
```

---

The output that you're getting (`'function toUpperCase() { [native code] }...`) is the result of each method being converted to a string, then concatenated to your result string. You can achieve the same result by running either of these commands in your console:

- `console.log("".toUpperCase);`
- `console.log("".toUpperCase.toString());`

The results of both are `function toUpperCase() { [native code] }`.

Happy coding!

Comment: I think it's more elegant to use a for loop for this case

Answer (score 3):

#### Use ES6 Syntax:

You could use ES6 features JavaScript has to offer which would reduce the source code:

```js
const convertString = str => [...str].map(char => char === char.toUpperCase() ? char.toLowerCase() : char.toUpperCase()).join('');

console.log(convertString("lower UPPER"));
```